# app.message returns undefined in console using Vue in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

I've just started learning Vue, and have been following there [intro guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/), but am stuck at the:

> Just open up your browser’s JavaScript console and set app.message to
> a different value.

I tried `app.message = 'test'` in Chrome's console, and it returns `"test"`, but the text doesn't change in the browser.

Also when I just run `app.message` before setting it to "test", it returns `undefined`.

**app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
});
```

**./bootstrap**

```
window._ = require('lodash');

window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap-sass');

window.Vue = require('vue');
require('vue-resource');

Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
    request.headers.set('X-CSRF-TOKEN', Laravel.csrfToken);

    next();
});
```

**test.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div id="app">
  @{{ message }}
</div>
@endsection
```

I'm guessing its something to do with what Laravel does since when I start a standalone html file it works as Vue says. I'm also new to Laravel so not to sure what's going on here.

Using Vue 2 and Laravel 5.3

Comment: What about this `const app = new Vue({
 data: {// your data}
}).$mount('#app')`

Comment: what's the html that the php file outputs?

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰 here is the html output: http://pastebin.com/dShmALK2

Comment: @Belmin does the same thing :(

Comment: Can you given a working link, maybe host it somewhere as you say its working on the HTML file and seems laravel specific, we might be able to debug properly after we can access the console of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as far as I can see from the live link is that its not the problem you anticipated at all.
app returns an HTML element collection and not a Vue object.
Try logging $vm(the Vue object) in your console and you will see the difference.
Maybe, try renaming the object from const app to vue(lowercase) as I think you(or the package manager or something) have used app somewhere else.

The reason why app.message returns "test" on console is that every console statement returns something. It returns undefined first because app(The HTML collection) doesn't have a property named message.

[image: Your live link console]

Comment: Legend! Also any idea why `test = new Vue` works but `var test = new Vue` doesn't? (as in the Vue guide they use var.

Comment: In one word, scope. When you use var test the variable declared is localized to the block it is declared in. When you don't use var, you are simply decalred as global therby being accessible in console. You can also try window.test=new Vue() ;